# Trying to dynamically create divs that can also be closed

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I'm trying to create a simple note taking application.

Right now I am trying figure out how to dynamically create and delete `DIV` elements. I can create `DIV`s, but each time I add a new `div` it adds a "Close" "X" to each previous `div`. So my question is how to I get the java script to only add one close "X" per `div`.

**My code is below for reference:**

```js
function more() {
 var createdDiv = document.createElement("div");//sets the variable 'createdDiv' to create a HTML 'div' elemnet
  createdDiv.className = "newDiv";
  //createdDiv.setAttribute("id", "newDiv"+i);//sets the class name of the created div to newDiv
  document.getElementById("top").insertBefore(createdDiv, document.getElementById("top").firstChild);
 for(i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('#top .newDiv').length; i++){
  var closeDiv = document.createElement("div");
  closeDiv.setAttribute("id", "close"+i);
  closeDiv.className = "close";
  closeDiv.innerHTML = "X";
  createdDiv.setAttribute("id", "note"+i);
  createdDiv.setAttribute("onclick", "trash()");
  document.getElementById("note"+i).insertBefore(closeDiv, document.getElementById("note"+i).firstChild);
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = i+1;
  }
  
 }
function trash() {
 for(i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('#top .newDiv').length; i++){
  var o = document.getElementById("close"+i);
  o.parentNode.removeChild(o);
}
}
```

```css
#header{
 height:150px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
#bottom{
 height:10px;
 background-color:blue; 
}
.newDiv{
 height:30px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:green;
 border:2px solid #000;
}
#menu{
 
 display:inline;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 position:relative;
 top:-60px;
 
}
#menu li{
 list-style-type: none;
 display:inline;
 padding-right: 
 
}
.item-padding{
  padding-right: 7%;
}
.one{
 Width: 50%;
 height:100px;
 background-color:#6CF; 
}
.fragment {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    height: 140px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #555;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fragment:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);

}

.fragment img { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}


.fragment h3 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #369;
}
.fragment h4 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
}
.close {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 3px;
    background:#ccc;
}

.close:hover {
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:2px 5px;
        background:#ccc;
    color:#fff;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Journal Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
     
    <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > div,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>

   
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="more();">MORE!</button>



<div id="top"></div>
<div onclick="trash();" id="test";" >Here</div> 
<div id="number"></div>  
<div class="one" id="two">
 <span onclick="" class="test" id="close">X</span>
</div>





</body>
<footer>
<script src="coffee.js"></script>
</footer>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Could you move your code to a working jsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/)? It's hard to spot the error here because I can't do any tests.

Comment: If you're including jQuery why not use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your for loop. It's really unnecessary as far as I can tell. The code could be cleaned up a bit, but to solve your issue I believe the following changes will work.

For some reason the code has been copied twice, use the first code snippet and test using the first "run code" button listed on this answer just below.

```js
function more() {
  var createdDiv = document.createElement("div");
  createdDiv.className = "newDiv";

  document.getElementById("top").insertBefore(createdDiv,document.getElementById("top").firstChild);
  var closeDiv = document.createElement("div");

  // set the length of the array to a variable.
  var arrayLength = document.querySelectorAll('#top .newDiv').length;

  closeDiv.setAttribute("id", "close"+ arrayLength);
  closeDiv.className = "close";
  closeDiv.innerHTML = "X";
  // Move trash function to "X".
  closeDiv.setAttribute("onclick", ("trash(" + arrayLength + ")"));


  createdDiv.setAttribute("id", "note"+ arrayLength);
  document.getElementById("note"+ arrayLength).insertBefore(closeDiv, document.getElementById("note"+document.querySelectorAll('#top .newDiv').length).firstChild);
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = arrayLength;


}

function trash(rowNum) {
  var o = document.getElementById("note"+rowNum);
  o.parentNode.removeChild(o);
  updateCounter(); // update the counter if you want to keep it.
}

function updateCounter(){
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = document.querySelectorAll('#top .newDiv').length;
}
```

```css
#header{
 height:150px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
#bottom{
 height:10px;
 background-color:blue; 
}
.newDiv{
 height:30px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:green;
 border:2px solid #000;
}
#menu{
 
 display:inline;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 position:relative;
 top:-60px;
 
}
#menu li{
 list-style-type: none;
 display:inline;
 padding-right: 
 
}
.item-padding{
  padding-right: 7%;
}
.one{
 Width: 50%;
 height:100px;
 background-color:#6CF; 
}
.fragment {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    height: 140px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #555;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fragment:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);

}

.fragment img { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}


.fragment h3 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #369;
}
.fragment h4 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
}
.close {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 3px;
    background:#ccc;
}

.close:hover {
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:2px 5px;
        background:#ccc;
    color:#fff;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Journal Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
     
    <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > div,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>

   
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="more();">MORE!</button>



<div id="top"></div>
<div onclick="trash();" id="test";" >Here</div> 
<div id="number"></div>  
<div class="one" id="two">
 <span onclick="" class="test" id="close">X</span>
</div>





</body>
<footer>
<script src="coffee.js"></script>
</footer>
</html>
```

```js
function more() {
 var createdDiv = document.createElement("div");//sets the variable 'createdDiv' to create a HTML 'div' elemnet
  createdDiv.className = "newDiv";
  //createdDiv.setAttribute("id", "newDiv"+i);//sets the class name of the created div to newDiv
  document.getElementById("top").insertBefore(createdDiv, document.getElementById("top").firstChild);
 for(i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('#top .newDiv').length; i++){
  var closeDiv = document.createElement("div");
  closeDiv.setAttribute("id", "close"+i);
  closeDiv.className = "close";
  closeDiv.innerHTML = "X";
  createdDiv.setAttribute("id", "note"+i);
  createdDiv.setAttribute("onclick", "trash()");
  document.getElementById("note"+i).insertBefore(closeDiv, document.getElementById("note"+i).firstChild);
  document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = i+1;
  }
  
 }
function trash() {
 for(i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('#top .newDiv').length; i++){
  var o = document.getElementById("close"+i);
  o.parentNode.removeChild(o);
}
}
```

```css
#header{
 height:150px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
#bottom{
 height:10px;
 background-color:blue; 
}
.newDiv{
 height:30px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:green;
 border:2px solid #000;
}
#menu{
 
 display:inline;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 position:relative;
 top:-60px;
 
}
#menu li{
 list-style-type: none;
 display:inline;
 padding-right: 
 
}
.item-padding{
  padding-right: 7%;
}
.one{
 Width: 50%;
 height:100px;
 background-color:#6CF; 
}
.fragment {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    height: 140px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #555;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fragment:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);

}

.fragment img { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}


.fragment h3 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #369;
}
.fragment h4 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
}
.close {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 3px;
    background:#ccc;
}

.close:hover {
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:2px 5px;
        background:#ccc;
    color:#fff;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Journal Test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
     
    <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > div,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>

   
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="more();">MORE!</button>



<div id="top"></div>
<div onclick="trash();" id="test";" >Here</div> 
<div id="number"></div>  
<div class="one" id="two">
 <span onclick="" class="test" id="close">X</span>
</div>





</body>
<footer>
<script src="coffee.js"></script>
</footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over the div collection and updating an ID and adding a close control. No need to do that, just create the close control and bind it to its associated div when you create it.

I don't know your full use case, but the IDs are unnecessary in the code you've posted. I've left them there in case you are using them for other processing, but there's no reason to have them for the add/remove use case.

It's also unclear what your `test` div is supposed to accomplish.

```js
var curId = 0;
var number = document.getElementById("number");

function makeCloser(closeControl, divToRemove) {
  var closer = function() {
    divToRemove.parentElement.removeChild(divToRemove);
  };
  closeControl.addEventListener('click', closer);
}

function more() {
  var createdDiv, closeDiv;

  // Create a close control
  closeDiv = document.createElement("div");
  closeDiv.className = "close";
  closeDiv.innerHTML = "X";

  // Create a new div
  createdDiv = document.createElement("div");
  createdDiv.className = "newDiv";
  createdDiv.setAttribute("id", curId++);
  
  // Add the count to the div, just to prove what we're removing with the close control
  createdDiv.innerHTML = curId;

  // add the close control to the new div
  createdDiv.appendChild(closeDiv);

  // Wire up the close function to the close control
  makeCloser(closeDiv, createdDiv);

  // Add the new div to the DOM
  document.getElementById("top").insertBefore(createdDiv, document.getElementById("top").firstChild);

  // Update the current div ID number
  number.innerHTML = curId;

}
```

```css
#header{
 height:150px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}
#bottom{
 height:10px;
 background-color:blue; 
}
.newDiv{
 height:30px;
 width:100%;
 background-color:green;
 border:2px solid #000;
}
#menu{
 
 display:inline;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 position:relative;
 top:-60px;
 
}
#menu li{
 list-style-type: none;
 display:inline;
 padding-right: 
 
}
.item-padding{
  padding-right: 7%;
}
.one{
 Width: 50%;
 height:100px;
 background-color:#6CF; 
}
.fragment {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: tahoma;
    height: 140px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #555;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.fragment:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);

}

.fragment img { 
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}


.fragment h3 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #369;
}
.fragment h4 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #000;
}
.close {
    float:right;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:2px 3px;
    background:#ccc;
}

.close:hover {
        float:right;
        display:inline-block;
        padding:2px 5px;
        background:#ccc;
    color:#fff;
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="more();">MORE!</button>
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="number"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `more()` function, you have a loop in which you add a closeDiv on each iteration. That means that you are adding as many 'X' divs in your newly created div as there are divs with `newDiv` class in the DOM.

I would change your method to something like this, even though I can't test it from here until you provide us a working fiddle with the full code and dependencies.

```
function more() {
        var createdDiv = document.createElement("div");//sets the variable 'createdDiv' to create a HTML 'div' elemnet
        createdDiv.className = "newDiv";
        //createdDiv.setAttribute("id", "newDiv"+i);//sets the class name of the created div to newDiv
        document.getElementById("top").insertBefore(createdDiv, document.getElementById("top").firstChild);
        var createdDivsQty = document.querySelectorAll('#top .newDiv').length;
        var closeDiv = document.createElement("div");
        closeDiv.setAttribute("id", "close"+createdDivsQty);
        closeDiv.className = "close";
        closeDiv.innerHTML = "X";
        createdDiv.setAttribute("id", "note"+createdDivsQty);
        createdDiv.setAttribute("onclick", "trash()");
        document.getElementById("note"+i).insertBefore(closeDiv, document.getElementById("note"+i).firstChild);
        document.getElementById("number").innerHTML = createdDivsQty+1;
}
```